# Tensorflow examples and tutorials missing from the pip package

Tags: python, tensorflow, build, pip, installation

When installing Tensorflow (e.g. `tensorflow-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.5.0) from pip, there is only the `tutorials/mnist` example in `tensorflow/examples`. It would be nice to have the examples available without having to get them separately from GitHub. Is there a reason why the rest of the examples are not included? Can they be included in future releases?

Comment: Looks like a bug report to tensorflow, rather than a question - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Comment: Thanks, did so. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17351